# Why isn't my code importing from another file to main file?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to keep my main file more clean that's why I've created a `columnsDefault` function which has the data that is required at `columns` at the main file.

My goal is to use that data at the `columns`, but for some reasons it is not working. Anyone might have a clue what's going on?

```js
function columnsDefault() {
    return (
        { key: "A", name: "A", editable: true },
        { key: "B", name: "B", editable: true },
        { key: "C", name: "C", editable: true },
        { key: "D", name: "D", editable: true },
        { key: "E", name: "E", editable: true },
        { key: "F", name: "F", editable: true },
        { key: "G", name: "G", editable: true },
        { key: "H", name: "H", editable: true },
        { key: "I", name: "I", editable: true },
        { key: "J", name: "J", editable: true },
        { key: "K", name: "K", editable: true },
        { key: "L", name: "L", editable: true },
        { key: "M", name: "M", editable: true },
        { key: "N", name: "N", editable: true },
        { key: "O", name: "O", editable: true },
        { key: "P", name: "P", editable: true },
        { key: "Q", name: "Q", editable: true },
        { key: "R", name: "R", editable: true },
        { key: "S", name: "S", editable: true },
        { key: "T", name: "T", editable: true },
        { key: "U", name: "U", editable: true },
        { key: "V", name: "V", editable: true },
        { key: "W", name: "W", editable: true },
        { key: "X", name: "X", editable: true },
        { key: "Y", name: "Y", editable: true },
        { key: "Z", name: "Z", editable: true }
    )
}

export default columnsDefault;
```

```js
import columnsDefault from './columnsDefault'

      columns: [
        columnsDefault
      ]
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error but I'm using these letters to create a table columns and the columns aren't being created, instead if I were to put the same data under `columns: [ ]` it would be created.

Comment: Your columnsDefault function should return an array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing the function to actual Array `[ ]`
Like this.

```js
const columnsDefault = [
    { key: "A", name: "A", editable: true },
    { key: "B", name: "B", editable: true },
    ...
    { key: "Z", name: "Z", editable: true }
]

export default columnsDefault;
```

And use it in another file without Array bracket should work.

```js
import columnsDefault from './columnsDefault'

columns: columnsDefault
```